# classList.remove no es una función

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de controlar con JS el contenido que se muestra al hacer click en un enlace. Al tratar de eliminar una etiqueta con classList salta un error de "no es una función" :

> TypeError: tab1516.classList.remove is not a function.

Utilizo bootstrap

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified margen-top col-lg-1">
 <li role="menubar" id="tab_1516"><a href="#palmares" onclick="mostrar1516()">Temp. 2015/16</a></li>
 <li role="menubar" id="tab_1617"><a href="#palmares" onclick="mostrar1617()">Temp. 2016/17</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified margen-top col-lg-1 oculta" id="nav-1516">
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#">Atletismo</a></li>
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#" onclick="muestraBalonmano1516()">Balonmano</a></li>
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#">Baloncesto</a></li>
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#">Esgrima</a></li>
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#">Lucha Canaria</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var nav1516 = document.getElementById('nav-1516');
var nav1617 = document.getElementById('nav-1617');
var tab1516 = document.getElementById('tab_1516');
var tab1617 = document.getElementById('tab_1617');

function mostrar1617(){
 tab1617.className = 'active';
 nav1617.style.display = 'block';

 nav1516.style.display = 'none';
 tab1516.classList.remove("active");
}
```

Comment: Parece que se trata de un error tipográfico. el id es `tab_1617` (con guión bajo) pero en la función lo llamas como `tab1617` (sin guión bajo). Por cierto, deberías incluir el error textual e indicar si estás usando bootstrap u otro framework. Referencia [mcve].

Comment: Mil disculpas, olvidé añadir la obtención de los ids. Obviamente no es ese el error, perdón por la confusión.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás cargando bootstrap? ¿Has verificado que las versiones de jQuery y Bootstrap sean compatibles?

Comment: Lo cargo desde el archivo .min que tengo almacenado en la carpeta css (última versión). No utilizo jQuery para esta parte, de todos modos como podría verificarlo?

Comment: Bootstrap requiere de jQuery, así que si no lo estás cargando, a eso se debe el problema.

Comment: jQuery está cargado pero a lo que me refiero es a que no es utilizado en esta parte del código. Por otro lado, si llamo desde consola a classList en cualquier elemento me devuelve la clase seguido de un "undefined", pero no he podido localizar información sobre esto :(

Comment: Perdona el señalamiento pero tienes un problema de concepto. Bootstrap requiere jQuery así que al usar Bootstrap estas usando jQuery. Deberías agregar mas líneas de código para que el código cumpla con lo indicado en [mcve]. En mi respuesta he colocado líneas de código para cargar jQuery y Bootstrap de maxcdn. Tal vez te convenga usar esas líneas para que puedas usar Stack Snippet en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

<s>El problema parece deberse a un error tipográfico, ya que el id es `tab_1617` (con guión bajo) pero en la función lo llama como `tab1617` (sin guión bajo).</s>

Asumiendo que se ha cargado las librerías/frameworks necesarios, con el código proporcionado por el OP no me ha sido posible reproducir el error.

A continuación se  comentan las líneas sobre los nodos con prefijo nav pues no fueron incluidos en el código original de la pregunta Las líneas para la carga de bootstrap fueron tomadas de https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp.

```js
//var nav1516 = document.getElementById('nav-1516');
//var nav1617 = document.getElementById('nav-1617');
var tab1516 = document.getElementById('tab_1516');
var tab1617 = document.getElementById('tab_1617');

function mostrar1617(){
 tab1617.className = 'active';
 //nav1617.style.display = 'block';

 //nav1516.style.display = 'none';
 tab1516.classList.remove("active");
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified margen-top col-lg-1">
 <li role="menubar" id="tab_1516"><a href="#palmares" onclick="mostrar1516()">Temp. 2015/16</a></li>
 <li role="menubar" id="tab_1617"><a href="#palmares" onclick="mostrar1617()">Temp. 2016/17</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified margen-top col-lg-1 oculta" id="nav-1516">
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#">Atletismo</a></li>
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#" onclick="muestraBalonmano1516()">Balonmano</a></li>
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#">Baloncesto</a></li>
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#">Esgrima</a></li>
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#">Lucha Canaria</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Como comenté anteriormente, pido disculpas porque no les mostré la obtención de los ids. Los ids que utilizo en la función son correctos

Comment: Ya taché lo de los ids, sin embargo, aún así no me es posible reproducir el error.

Answer (score -1):

Hola te cuento que tu error se debe a que no tienes ninguna clase con el nombre active en tu código deberías colocar algo así:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified margen-top col-lg-1">
 <li role="menubar" id="tab_1516" class="active"><a href="#palmares" onclick="mostrar1516()">Temp. 2015/16</a></li>
 <li role="menubar" id="tab_1617"><a href="#palmares" onclick="mostrar1617()">Temp. 2016/17</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified margen-top col-lg-1 oculta" id="nav-1516">
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#">Atletismo</a></li>
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#" onclick="muestraBalonmano1516()">Balonmano</a></li>
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#">Baloncesto</a></li>
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#">Esgrima</a></li>
 <li role="menubar"><a href="#">Lucha Canaria</a></li>
</ul>
```

Como puedes ver he colocado la clase active (class="active")  ahora si podrá reconocer el script la función remove, te dejo un enlace donde podrás ver más ejemplos:

[Remove ejemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_classlist_remove)

Comment: Si bien es válido incluir enlaces a fiddles, este sitio cuenta con su propia herramienta para código HTML/CSS/JavaScript. En https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/429/65 se incluyen capturas de pantalla sobre cómo usarlo.

Comment: La clase active se crea mediante otra función. Aún así, he probado lo que me comentas y tampoco funciona :(